# VSTS work item query to include both not assigned work items and the ones assigned to me

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I need to locate all work items in my VSTS project, that either are not assigned to anyone - or is assigned to myself - how do I make a query like that?

State should be not Resolved, not removed, not completed, not closed, but I can handle those :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, make a query with:

`Assigned To = @Me`

Or

`Assigned To =`

[image]